# NSString to NSData conversion

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata

I am having following NSString:
8270be11a217f1420863d76ea7d24820

and i want to convert in following format:
NSData : <8270be11 a217f142 0863d76e a7d24820>

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: @MazIqbal That is not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: What exact your need, You mean in that format of string as a NSData OR encoded string as NSData..

Comment: @KumarKI : i need output as NSData which will have following output when i Print it using NSLog(@"MyData : %@,data); 
Output : <8270be11 a217f142 0863d76e a7d24820>

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this..

```
   NSString* str = @"teststring";
   NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This doesn't come close to answering the question.